# android.os.Message and JMM

Tags: java, android, java-memory-model

Correct me if I am wrong, but we don't do any synchronization, while changing values of `Message` and also `Message`'s fields are not volatile. So, why do we still got actual values (not cached ones) in the thread, that handles message? Maybe it's obvious, but I am new to JMM.

Comment: " changing values of Message " what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink reusing message and setting new values to it's fields

Comment: you cannot reuse a Message,  each time you want to sent it via a Handler you have to obtain() a new Message,  so its still unclear what you actually need to know

Comment: @pskink actually, all Messages are pooled, so `obtain()` returns a message from message pool

Comment: yes,  but you cannot for example use a Message that is passed in Handler.handleMessage and resend it without obtaining a new one

Comment: @pskink ofcourse, but I meant that:
1) Message was handled and added back to pool
2) Message was obtained again and sent to the same thread (the thread we sent to before)

Comment: ok,  and your problem/concern really is?  seems i don't  understand your original question..